# msysgit profile folder with unicode on windows 7

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8, msysgit

I have msysgit installed on windows 7, my profile folder contains unicode characters and looks like `C:\Users\Андрей`

I cannot get ssh working, have this message:

```
>ssh -T git@github.com
Could not create directory '/c/Users/\200\255\244\340\245\251/.ssh'.
```

.git/gitconfig have this string:

```
[core]
    quotepath = false

[i18n]
        commitencoding = cp1251
        logoutputencoding = cp1251
```

This as I see doesn't affect path. Then I patched $HOME in Git/etc/profile:
`export HOME="/d/Dropbox/My\ Documents/"`
But it doesn't change anything. I still get `Could not create directory` for ssh.

It works for ssh with
`set HOME=/d/Dropbox/My Documents`
from command line.

But it is only works for `ssh -T git@github.com` not `git push`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar though somewhat unrelated problem with unicode characters but this may help you.  You may need to set the codepage of your environment.  You can try using the chcp command to change the windows console codepage:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: nope, it wasn't useful for ssh and ls
`>git checkout русский
>chcp 1251
>dir
русский
>ls
???????
>chcp 866
>ls
???????
>chcp 855
>ls
???????`

Comment: `>git push -u origin master` and the same message:
`Could not create directory '/c/Users/\200\255\244\340\245\251/.ssh'.`

Comment: It's odd (well it's MS so it's not) but that documentation is missing a lot of code pages.  Give `chcp 65001` a try, it is UTF-8 which is the most universally supported.